# Finding the Kernel of a specific group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group. Say that map $σ_g = gxg^\mathrm{-1}$.

We know that $σ_g \in Aut(G)$ by the nature of a bijective homomorphism. (I can provide the proof for this if people desire.)

I have already proven that the map $ϕ: G → Aut(G)$ defined by $ϕ(g) = σ_g$ is a group homomorphism.

I'm trying to figure out *what* the kernel of $ϕ$ is. I think if it's trivial, then $ϕ$ will be injective, based on other questions on here.

I know that the kernel is the set of $g \in G$ such that $ϕ$ sends g to the identity map. Not sure how to apply this.

Comment: You know that $g \in \ker \phi \iff \forall x \in G~(g^{-1}xg=x)$.  Multiply that equation on the left by $g$ and what happens?

Comment: xg = gx for all x in G. $g \in \{e\}$ So the kernel is trivial for all x in G?

Comment: So... I guess nontrivial abelian groups don't exist, then?

Comment: Yes to your first sentence.  It's possible (in fact common) for non-identity elements to satisfy that condition.  And remember, $\phi$ is a homomorphism *from* $G$, so the issue is simply whether any particular element $g \in G$ is or is not in $\ker \phi$.  When asking this question, $x$ has nothing to do with anything other than to identify suitable elements of $G$.  Suppose $G= (\Bbb Q \setminus \{0 \}, \cdot)$.  What is $\phi$?

Comment: A useful example to keep in mind is the general linear group $GL_n$. Can you find some matrices that commute with all others?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's an interesting point. Not sure why you phrased the comment like that though.

Comment: Because when you asserted that if $gx=xg$ for all $g$ in $G$ then it must be the case that $x=e$, you asserted that the only abelian group is $\{e\}$.

Comment: @RobertShore So for your example, G is a countably infinite Abelian group. Finding the automorphic groups of G is an challenge in of itself. $ϕ$ maps from non-zero rational numbers to the automorphic group of the non-zero rational numbers. I'm not really sure where you're going with this.

Comment: You don't need to know what *all* automorphisms of the nonzero rationals are; you have the map $\phi$, and you know *exactly* where it sends any element of the nonzero rationals. It sends $q$ to the map $\sigma_q$. Now compute what $\sigma_q$ does to an arbitrary nonzero rational $r$, to determine the map $\sigma_q$. You should have absolutely no trouble at all figuring that out.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g\in\ker\phi$. Then $\phi(g)=\sigma_e$, the identity map. Therefore, we have

\begin{align*}
\sigma_g=\sigma_e&\iff gxg^{-1}=x&\forall x\in G\\
&\iff gx=xg&\forall x\in G\\
&\iff g\in Z(G),
\end{align*}

where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$, i.e., the group of all elements of $G$ that commute with every element of $G$. Indeed, if $Z(G)=\{e\}$ (although it need not be), then $\ker\phi$ is trivial, and $\phi$ is injective. An example of the center being non-trivial would be any abelian group, since if $G$ is an abelian group, then we have that $Z(G)=G$.